# Navigate to URL is not refreshing the page in lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have a vf page in lightning which opens up on button click from the case detail page. The vf page will close the case upon save. I have an oncomplete method in vf page which navigates to the case detail page once database update is done. The case detail is not getting refreshed. How can i refresh the page?

Can any one help me in this regard.

I tried using page reference without using on complete, even in there the page is not getting refreshed.

## vf page with on complete

```
function refreshpage() {
        alert("method invoked 1");
        var caseId='{!record.Id}';

        if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
            window.top.location = '{!JSENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.parent_domain)}/console';
        }if({!$User.UITheme == 'Theme4d'}){
            alert('Lightning-->'+caseId);
            sforce.one.navigateToURL('/one/one.app#/sObject/'+caseId+'/view',true);               

        } 
        else {    
            window.top.location = '/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}';  
        }
```

---

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" rendered="{!displayItems}" oncomplete="refreshpage();"/>
```

## Controller with page reference

```
public PageReference  save()
{
    update record;

    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + record.Id);
    return pageRef;
    //return controller.view();
}
```

I have tried all the below possibilities nothing seems to be working.

> //window.open(window.location.origin+'/one/one.app#/sObject/'+caseId+'/view','_parent');
>                   //sforce.one.navigateToSObject(caseId);
>                   //window.location.href='/one/one.app#/sObject/'+caseId+'/view';
>                   // window.top.location = '/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}';
>                   // $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); 
>                   //Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name : "publisher.refresh", payload : { feed:true }});
>                   //Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name : 'publisher.refresh', payload : {feed: true, objectFields: true,
>   objectRelatedLists: {}}});
>                   //window.reload(true);
>                   //window.close();
>                   //sforce.one.navigateToURL('/one/one.app#/sObject/'+caseId+'/view',true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per salesforce this seems to be a know issue. Intermittent fix will be released in spring 18.

Comment: do you have a link to the known issue?

Comment: Here is the link for known issue
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C8QQAU&title=data-not-updated-in-ui-after-an-apex-update-in-lightning-experience

Comment: Is there any workaround for the same?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript won't understand the Sforce function. You can use this to navigate to another window:

`window.open(window.location.origin+'/'+"/one/one.app#/sObject/'+caseId+'/view'",'_parent');`

You can use `'_blank'` to open it in new tab also and keep the parent window as it is.

Comment: Its not getting refreshed, it is opening the case in the detail mode(not getting the updated value from db) + another window of the vf page.

Comment: I have a raised a case with salesforce and this seems to be a know issue. Intermittent fix will be released in spring 18.